# HTML: Table does not create new row for my posts

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am currently using Laravel to retrieve posts from a database and displaying them in a table one by one. Each row will represent a different post.It should work but im not sure what the issue is, it only creates 2 rows. One row is for the column titles and only one-row for all the posts instead of 7 rows for 7 posts as an example.

Here is my code for displaying the posts in a table:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row posts">
        <table class="post">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th><th>Date Posted and Author</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <td>i</td> 
                <td>i</td> 
                <td>{{ $post->body }}</td>
                <td>Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
```

Ignore the first 2 columns that where I put 'i', it is just a placeholder.

Comment: Hard to create **rows** without a `<tr>` table **row** element :P

Comment: You aren't wrapping your `td` elements in the `foreach` in a `tr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't use `<tr>` tag

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row posts">
        <table class="post">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th><th>Date Posted and Author</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                <td>i</td> 
                <td>i</td> 
                <td>{{ $post->body }}</td>
                <td>Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</td>
               </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `<tr>` in your loop. Try this..

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
            <tr>
            <td>i</td> 
            <td>i</td> 
            <td>{{ $post->body }}</td>
            <td>Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--hope this works to create rows -->
<div class="container">
<section class="row posts">
    <table class="post">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th>
             <th>Date Posted and Author</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach($posts as $post)
              <tr>
            <td>i</td> 
            <td>i</td> 
            <td>{{ $post->body }}</td>
            <td>Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} 
              {{ $post->user->last_name }} on 
              {{ $post->created_at }}</td></tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>enter code here
   </section>
    </div>
```